# Inactivate duplicate record and re-point child records to active one

Tags: oracle

There are two table as below

Table1

```
ID Name Age Active PID
-----------------------------
1   A    2   Y     100
2   A    2   Y     100
3   A    2   Y     100
4   B    3   Y     200
5   B    3   Y     200
```

Table2

```
T2ID CID  
---------
10    1    
20    1    
30    1    
40    2    
50    2    
60    3
70    3
80    3
90    4
100   5
110   5
```

I am trying to inactivate the duplicate record of table 1 and reassign the table2 record to activated rows of table 1,The result for table1 and table2 should be as below

```
ID Name Age Active PID
-----------------------------
1   A    2   Y     100
2   A    2   N     100
3   A    2   N     100
4   B    3   N     200
5   B    3   Y     200

T2ID CID  
---------
10    1    
20    1    
30    1    
40    1    
50    1    
60    1
70    1
80    1
90    5
100   5
110   5
```

please help for oracle query to update

Comment: ID | Name | Age | Active | PID
1   |    A        |  2    |    Y          | 100
2   |    A        |  2    |    Y          | 100
3   |    A        |  2    |    Y          | 100
4   |    B        |  3    |    Y          | 200
5   |    B        |  3    |    Y          | 200

Comment: What is the link that determines the ids in table one belong together? Is it Name or is it PID?

Comment: link that determines the ids in table one belong together is PID

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using two merge statements, like so:

Update table2:

```
MERGE INTO table2 tgt
  USING (WITH t1 AS (SELECT ID,
                            NAME,
                            age,
                            active,
                            pid,
                            MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY pid) min_id,
                            CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN active = 'Y' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY pid) > 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END multi_active_rows
                     FROM   table1)
         SELECT t2.t2id,
                t2.cid old_cid,
                t1.min_id new_cid
         FROM   t1
                INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.cid
         WHERE  t1.multi_active_rows = 'Y') src
    ON (tgt.t2id = src.t2id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.cid = src.new_cid;
```

Update table1:

```
MERGE INTO table1 tgt
  USING (WITH t1 AS (SELECT ID,
                            NAME,
                            age,
                            active,
                            pid,
                            MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY pid) min_id,
                            CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN active = 'Y' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY pid) > 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END multi_active_rows
                     FROM   table1)
         SELECT ID
         FROM   t1
         WHERE  multi_active_rows = 'Y'
         AND    ID != min_id) src
    ON (tgt.id = src.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET active = 'N';
```

Since we want to derive the results to update both `table1` and `table2` from the original dataset in table1, it's easier to update `table2` first before updating table1.

This works by finding the lowest `id` across each set of `pid`s in table1, plus checking to see if there is more than one active row for each `pid` (there's no need to do any updates if we have at most one active row available).

Once we have that information, we can use that to decide which rows to update in each table, and we can use the `min_id` to update `table2` with, and we can update any rows in table1 where the `id` doesn't match the `min_id` to be not active.

N.B. If you could have a mix of `Y`s and `N`s in your data, you may need to skip the `and id != min_id` check in the second merge statement and amend the update part to update the row to `Y` if the `id` is the `min_id`, otherwise set it to `N`.

Comment: You probably need to edit `t1`->`table1` and `t2`-> `table2` in the `MERGE INTO` part.